# Don't allow toll free numbers in php preg_match regexp

Tags: php, preg-match

Hi am working on some maintenance project. But on that code someone added the preg_match expression for not allowing the toll free numbers.. Toll free numbers start with area codes 800, 888, 877, 866, 855 or 844. They will be formatted as 800-xxx-xxxx or 1-800-xxx-xxxx or (800) xxx-xxxx or 800xxxxxxx or 1800xxxxxxx. etc.

If the number is a toll free number, throw an error "Please enter a local phone number here, not a toll free number." 
Below is my code:-

```
$getphone = $_POST['phone'];
    /* ISSUE: This catches 
            1-800-450-7006 
            1 (800) 450-7006 
            1(800) 450-7006 
        but is not catching
            (800) 450-7006
            */
    if(!preg_match('/^(?!(?:1-)?(\\$|#|8(00|55|66|77|88)))\(?[\\s.-]*([0-9]{3})?[\\s.-]*\)?[\\s.-]*[0-9]{3}[\\s.-]*[0-9]{4}$/', $getphone)){
        // Need to redirect back, not to profile
       echo 'Please enter a local phone number here, not a toll free number'; die;
    }
```

Can anyone help me how to check for this case (800) 450-7006. Thanks

Comment: The easiest way would be to strip all non number characters out first, then check.

Comment: @aynber can you post answer?

Comment: Try `^(?!(?:1-)?(?:\$|#|(?:\((8(?:00|55|66|77|88))\)|(?1))))\(?[\s.-]*([0-9]{3})?[\s.-]*\)?[\s.-]*[0-9]{3}[\s.-]*[0-9]{4}$`, see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZhdjTJ/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hey post your answer i will accept it

Comment: I use `preg_replace('/[^x0-9]/', '', $value);` to clean out phone numbers. It leaves an `x` for extensions.

Comment: @kunal I posted the answer. If you need other enhacements you may drop me comments below my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest "excluding" specific numbers inside (or not) parentheses at the start:

```
'~^(?!(?:1-)?(?:\$|#|(?:\((8(?:00|55|66|77|88))\)|(?1))))\(?[\s.-]*([0-9]{3})?[\s.-]*\)?[\s.-]*[0-9]{3}[\s.-]*[0-9]{4}$~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZhdjTJ/1)

I replaced `8(00|55|66|77|88)` with `(?:\((8(?:00|55|66|77|88))\)|(?1))`, a non-capturing group matching two alternatives:

- `\((8(?:00|55|66|77|88))\)` - `(`, `800`, `855`, `866`, `877`, `888` and then `)`
- `|` - or
- `(?1)` - the whole `8(?:00|55|66|77|88)`, Group 1, pattern.

Comment: thanks for helping me.. your answer is short and simple. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: can you guide you to create regexp.. i am very bad in creating regexp... i am tottaly dependent on the google for regexp :(

Comment: @kunal Please explain what you mean.

Comment: i mean i don't know how to create regexp... the code you have done i just copy and paste ... but i don't knw the working... even i don't knw the basic regexp :(

Comment: I thought you wrote that pattern and only wanted to add some exception to it. I will add details a bit later.

Comment: No no i am doing on some maintenance project.. i am just doing updation in code according to my client

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

 /* 800, 888, 877, 866, 855 or 844. They will be formatted as
    800-xxx-xxxx or 1-800-xxx-xxxx or (800) xxx-xxxx or
    800xxxxxxx or 1800xxxxxxx */

 $phone = $_POST['phone']; 

 // remove everything that is not a number
 $phone = preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $phone);

 // look for your pattern in the "cleaned" string
 if(!preg_match('/^1?8(88|77|66|55|44|00)/', $phone)){
  echo 'error';
 }

?>
```